# $P(X-np>n\varepsilon)\leq E\{e^{\lambda \cdot (X-np-n\varepsilon) }\}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, summation, binomial-coefficients

For $X \mathtt{\sim} \text{Bin}(n,p), \lambda > 0, \varepsilon > 0$, how do you show the following? $$P(X-np>n\varepsilon)\leq E\{e^{\lambda \cdot (X-np-n\varepsilon) }\}$$
Unless I made some error, it's pretty easy to see that:
$$E\{e^{\lambda \cdot (X-np-n\varepsilon) }\}=e^{-n\varepsilon\lambda}$$

The LHS is giving me more problems:
 $$P(X-np > n\varepsilon) = \sum_{i=n\varepsilon + np+1}^{n} \binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i} \text{  for }n\varepsilon+np \in \mathbb{Z}$$
$$P(X-np > n\varepsilon) = \sum_{i=\lceil n\varepsilon + np\rceil}^{n} \binom{n}{i}p^i(1-p)^{n-i} \text{  for }n\varepsilon+np \notin \mathbb{Z}$$

I'm not sure where to go from here, or even if I am on the right track. Could someone please provide some hints?

Comment: $E\{e^{\lambda \cdot (X-np-n\varepsilon) }\}=e^{-n\varepsilon\lambda}$: this doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: Since $e^x$ is monotone and $\lambda,\epsilon > 0$, 
$$
E\{e^{\lambda\cdot (X-np-n\epsilon)\}=e^{-\lambda np - \lambda n\epsilon}E\{e^{\lambda X}\}=e^{-\lambda np - \lambda n\epsilon}e^{lambda EX}=e^{-\lambda np - \lambda n\epsilon}e^{lambda np}=e^{np\epsilon}
$$

Comment: If I correctly parsed your comment, you're using the "fact" that $E\{e^{\lambda X}\} = e^{\lambda EX}$.  But this is false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using Markov's Inequality?

$P(X-np>n\varepsilon)=P(e^{\lambda(X-np)}>e^{\lambda n\varepsilon})\leq \frac{\mathbb{E}(e^{\lambda (X-np)})}{e^{\lambda n\varepsilon}}=\mathbb{E}(e^{\lambda (X-np-n\varepsilon)})$

Comment: That does it! I hadn't thought to try that.

Comment: This is often referred to as the Chernoff bound, but importantly this holds for all lambda>0. One can get a tighter bound by computing the infimum over lambda>0